# Shorthand way of assigning default value to optional String?

Tags: typescript

I have a variable read from a network call of type optional `String`:

```
const someName = data.someName
```

I want to construct a `String` using that variable and assign a default value to it when it's `null`. Is there an inline or shorthand way of doing this?

```
const someString = "You received something from " + someName
```

Comment: `someName ?? "defaultValue"` in TS3.7+ or `someName || "defaultValue"` in any version except that the latter will use the default if `someName` is the empty string, which may or may not be okay.

Comment: Would you mind making that an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[TypeScript 3.7 introduced support](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#nullish-coalescing) for the [proposed JavaScript "nullish coalescing operatior" `??`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-nullish-coalescing/).  The syntax looks like `someName ?? defaultValue` and evaluates to `someName` unless that is `null` or `undefined`, in which case it evaluates to `defaultValue`.  (So "nullish" means `null` or `undefined`.) This is a [short-circuiting operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation) so if `someName` is non-nullish then `defaultValue` will not be evaluated at all.

Before TypeScript 3.7 you could always use a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to achieve a similar result: `someName != null ? someName : defaultValue`.

But if you don't care specifically about `null` and `undefined` and don't mind using the default if `someName` is any [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value (like the empty string `""`), then you can just use [the logical "or" operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR): `someName || defaultValue`, which also short-circuits.

Any of those should work for you.  Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBBIFsCmA5AhsmBeGBZNUAFgHQBOaYAJogBQCUMAPDAAzECsMA-DAEQCCAGwCWwJLxgAuGGACugwQG4AsAChQkWJSQAzNPKgA1NINlJsfAEIgARrzVqN8QUmKCQAcxrxk6TFx5tPQNjUyQ6RRgAeiiYIVFzEFIYaxsYR3BnV3cvH1QMcwBCHDkFbjhEfMxpIP1BIxMzCOjY+LEYJJTbDMgQFzdPb0q-cwAfUZhakMbwyJi4kXbO1KA)

Answer (score 1):

I like template literals. Maybe you can combine this with ternary operator to give a default value once it has `null` or `undefined` value.

Try the following:

```js
const data = {};
const someString = `You received something from ${data.someName ? data.someName : 'your default value'}`;
console.log(someString);
```

Read further here:

1. [Template literals (Template strings)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)
2. [Conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

I hope that helps!